# nginx returns 403 forbidden on subdirectory

Tags: nginx, subdirectory

I have this simple configuration

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        proxy_pass             http://localhost:5055;
        proxy_set_header       Host $host;
    }

    location /schifezze/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8931/;
    }

    location /subdir/ {
        root /var/www/html/subdir/;
    }
```

}

And I always get a 403 when accessing myserver/subdir it from the browser. 777 on all the files in subdir.

I know I'm doing something wrong here, please help!

Comment: does the error still persist when you point to another subdirectory? or in the `/var/www/html/` as well?

Comment: By default nginx does not produce directory listings. If that's what you want, then use https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html

Comment: doesn't work either with another subdirectory or with autoindex on